# how to output multiple scss files in style dictionary

Tags: style-dictionary

How can we output multiple scss files based on json keys in style guide with style dictionary. Design studio outputs JSON which further needs to be split into multiple scss files

```
{
  "source": ["tokens/**/*.json"],
  "platforms": {
    "scss": {
      "transformGroup": "scss",
      "buildPath": "build/scss/",
      "files": [{
        "destination": "_variables.scss",
        "format": "scss/variables"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```